# Is there any GUI for Intel P-state fine-tuning?

Tags: power-management

I like using `indicator-cpufreq`, but I'd also like to use Intel P-state, as it sound like promising. The problem is, you can't really control it's behavior. I've tested it a lot and came to conclusion that pstate's powersave is not that powersave when compared to cpufreq's one. My cpu runs pretty decent at minimum clock (800MHz) and when I am on battery - that's all I really want.

`cpupower` provides some low-level interface to control P-state, but tuning it is kinda troublesome. In windows there are several power modes and you can tweak it. Having only 2 options (performance and powersave) in linux is kinda sad.

So, my question is: are there any GUI tools to tweak P-state and have control similar to what classic cpufreq provided?

Comment: on gnome there is this  extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager/ ... anyway from my understanding  the modern intel cpu `ix` series have a hw control for frequency and `p-state` driver if it find this hw capability demand the control directly to the cpu.

Comment: Cool, that is at least something, though I don't use GNOME.

Comment: Actually I think there is not way to bypass the hw control ( at least on my cpu i5 sandybridge) ... that is sad because I have some games that works fine but they overheat the cpu so I need a way to limit the cpu and so the temperature ... `thermald` is a kind of  over complicated to configure and there is no much stuff that on internet ( only man pages :(